# cannot start an activity via an Intent from the nav drawer

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer, forceclose

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer and use it in multiple activities. But when I try to start another activity (when I click on the item in the navigation drawer), the app crashes and displays a force close message.
Here is my Main activity called Home:

```
package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_new);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent;

        if(position == 0)
        {

        }

       else if(position == 1)
        {
            try {
                intent = new Intent(Home.this, MyTasks.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("exception occurred: " + e);
            }

        }
        else if(position == 2)
        {
            intent = new Intent(Home.this, Group_tasks.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if(position == 3)
        {
            intent = new Intent(Home.this, What_do_I_miss.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "An error has occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_new, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Here is my interface:

```
package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

public interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
```

NavigationDrawerAdapter:

```
package com.radoslav.socialreminder;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NavigationItem> mData;
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    private View mSelectedView;
    private int mSelectedPosition;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(List<NavigationItem> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public NavigationDrawerCallbacks getNavigationDrawerCallbacks() {
        return mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(NavigationDrawerCallbacks navigationDrawerCallbacks) {
        mNavigationDrawerCallbacks = navigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row, viewGroup, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        viewHolder.itemView.setClickable(true);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                                       if (mSelectedView != null) {
                                                           mSelectedView.setSelected(false);
                                                       }
                                                       mSelectedPosition = viewHolder.getPosition();
                                                       v.setSelected(true);
                                                       mSelectedView = v;
                                                       if (mNavigationDrawerCallbacks != null)
                                                           mNavigationDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(viewHolder.getPosition());
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_selector);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());
        viewHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mData.get(i).getDrawable(), null, null, null);
        if (mSelectedPosition == i) {
            if (mSelectedView != null) {
                mSelectedView.setSelected(false);
            }
            mSelectedPosition = i;
            mSelectedView = viewHolder.itemView;
            mSelectedView.setSelected(true);
        }
    }


    public void selectPosition(int position) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        }
    }
}
```

And NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.lang.String;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    private String item1 = "Home";
    private String item2 = "My tasks";
    private String item3 = "Group tasks";
    private String item4 = "What do I miss?";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println(item1);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer_new, container, false);
        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return view;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {


        List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem(item1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(item2, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(item3, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(item4, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     * @param toolbar      The Toolbar of the activity.
     */
    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
        ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

This is what the logcat spits out when the app crashes:

```
08-07 14:42:16.765      941-941/com.radoslav.socialreminder I/System.out﹕ Home
08-07 14:42:16.775      941-941/com.radoslav.socialreminder D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-07 14:42:16.775      941-941/com.radoslav.socialreminder W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b30700)
08-07 14:42:16.790      941-941/com.radoslav.socialreminder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radoslav.socialreminder/com.radoslav.socialreminder.MyTasks}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:94)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:87)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:79)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:198)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:96)
            at com.radoslav.socialreminder.MyTasks.onCreate(MyTasks.java:26)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 14:42:16.795    2430-2780/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Notify an ApplicationCrash
```

Comment: The problem is in MyTask.class, line 26, Can you show it please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, here is the MyTasks.class but I have commented out most of it

```
package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyTasks extends ActionBarActivity{
     //   implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_tasks);
       /* mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);*/
    }

 /*   @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_new, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```